# Microsoft Access: Different Queries Based On Input

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, interactive

I want to create a form that includes a drop-down list of queries, and then a button that when i press it, runs the query which i have selected from that drop-down.

I don't mind manually filling in the drop-down and then adding comparison code if that is possible. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The problem is running the query. The action of buttons restricts me to a specific query, but I want that to be dependent on which query I choose from the combo box.

Comment: "The action of buttons restricts me to a specific query" - Only if you only use the GUI and/or wizards. If you write VBA there is no such restriction. See Minty's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate a combo or probably better a listbox using the following query. 
This would list all queries that were named starting with qryRep... and display them as Rep...

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name, Mid([Name],4) AS QueryName
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (((Left([Name],6))="qryRep"))
ORDER BY MsysObjects.Name;
```

By restricting the display to a named group, you don't list every query in the database.

To run the query from the double click event of the list box - assuming it was called lstQueries;

```
 Private Sub lstQueries_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

        Dim txtQueryName     As String

        txtQueryName = Me.lstQueries
        DoCmd.OpenQuery txtQueryName , acViewNormal, acReadOnly
 End sub
```

This will open the query in a read only view.

Comment: The problem is running the query. The action of buttons restricts me to a specific query, but I want that to be dependent on which query I choose from the combo box.